# CGAL voronoi diagram metric

Tags: c++, cgal, voronoi

There is an implementation of VD for segments in CGAL library, but it works only for Euclidean metrics case. Is it possible to use my own metric function there?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should theoretically be possible, but not easy to do. Changing the metric implies changing all the predicates and constructions (which is quite a lot of work). You must provide a new model of [SegmentDelaunayGraphTraits_2](http://www.cgal.org/Manual/latest/doc_html/cgal_manual/Segment_Delaunay_graph_2_ref/Concept_SegmentDelaunayGraphTraits_2.html) concept.